# Swagger reusing examples showing weird $$ref element

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I wrote a swagger specification Yaml file and in the `components` section I have:

```
examples:
  companyExample:
    company:
      id: uNiquEiD
      name: Company Name
```

I use this `companyExample` in the response as following:

```
example:
  $ref: '#/components/examples/companyExample'
```

Here is the output:

[image]

So what is this extra `"$$ref": "#/components/examples/companyExample"` is it a bug? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `example` keyword (not to be confused with multiple `exampleS`) does not support `$ref`. The whole example value must be specified inline:

```yaml
example:
  company:
    id: uNiquEiD
    name: Company Name
```

To `$ref` an example defined in `#/components/examples`, you'll need to use the `examples` keyword. `examples` can be used in parameters, request bodies, response bodies and response headers but NOT in schemas. In other words, `examples` can be used 
*alongside* `schema` but not *inside* `schema`.

For instance, to `$ref` an example as a response example, you would use the following. Note that the example definition uses the [`value`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#exampleObject) keyword to wrap the actual example value. (The example definition in your original question is not valid because of the missing `value`.)

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Company'
              examples:
                companyExample:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/companyExample'

components:
  examples:
    companyExample:
      summary: Sample company data
      value:
        # The actual example value begins here
        company:
          id: uNiquEiD
          name: Company Name
```

**Note for Swagger UI users:** Support for multiple `examples` is available in Swagger UI 3.23.0+ and Swagger Editor 3.6.31+.

Comment: Hi @Helen, thanks for the info I didn't know rendering it is not implemented yet in Swagger UI.